# How can I group a bunch of buttons in groups of 10s (in a div)?

Tags: html, pug

```
    div#container
        each account in accounts
                button #{account.stuff}
```

I want to group the buttons inside a div. Every div has to have 10 (or less if there's some left over).

I would prefer to not use any JS. Altough, if necessary, a bit of CSS is fine (I would prefer just Pug)

I tried using a grid, but dont want to use CSS.
I tried using ifs and mods, but that just creates an empty  without actually any buttons.

Answer (score -1):

I would approach this with two loops and a conditional. It's much more legible to me than a `.reduce()` method.

```
- const numberPerDiv = 10
#container
  - for (let i = 0; i < Math.ciel(accounts.length / numberPerDiv); i++)
    div
      - for (let j = 0; j < numberPerDiv; j++)
        if accounts[i + j]
          button #{accounts[i + j].stuff}
```

The outer loop creates the appropriate number of container divs based on the length of the `accounts` array. If there's 36 accounts, with 10 in a div, it will create 4 divs. (36 / 10 = 3.6, which rounds up to 4).

Then the inner loop creates each button by accessing the appropriate index of the `accounts` array, if it exists.